# Prevent alert while converting Word to PDF in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word, wordtopdf

I am converting docs in a folder to PDF using the code below

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(txtFolderPath.Text, "*.doc",
                                          SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                  foreach (string path in filePaths)
                {
                    Application app = new Application();
                    app.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
                    app.Visible = true;

                    var objPresSet = app.Documents;
                    var objPres = objPresSet.Open(path, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
                    var temppath = path;
                    var pdfFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(path, ".pdf");
                    var pdfPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), pdfFileName);

                    try
                    {
                        objPres.ExportAsFixedFormat(
                            pdfPath,
                            WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF,
                            false,
                            WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForPrint,
                            WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument
                        );
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        pdfPath = null;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        objPres.Close();                      
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
                    }
```

But for every document I am getting the pop up below eventhough I have set the alerts to none.
[image]

Since the number of files are huge how can I stop this alert programatically in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set  your second parameter to `MsoTriState.msoFalse` like so:

```
var objPres = objPresSet.Open(
                path, 
                MsoTriState.msoFalse /* ConfirmConversions */, 
                MsoTriState.msoTrue, 
                MsoTriState.msoFalse);
```

because you're looking at the Convert File dialog and the *ConfirmConversions* controls whether that dialog is thrown in your face or not:

> True to display the Convert File dialog box if the file isn't in Microsoft Word format.

This is mentioned in the [Documents.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.open) specification on MSDN.

It looks like not all your *.doc files are actual Word documents, hence the Convert File dialog popping up. I assume Word will throw an exception if its dreamed up conversion (in your example from Rich Text Format) turns out to be wrong, aka not an RTF fileformat.